# Android 10 : Reason for dotted lines drawn along with crop selection frame when images selected from Gallery for setting wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

The below is the source code of Android 10 Gallery application,

**packages/apps/Gallery2/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/Wallpaper.java**

```
Point size = getDefaultDisplaySize(new Point());
float spotlightX = (float) size.x / width;
float spotlightY = (float) size.y / height;
```

**packages/apps/Gallery2/src/com/android/gallery3d/filtershow/crop/CropView.java**

```
 public void setWallpaperSpotlight(float spotlightX, float spotlightY) {
    mSpotX = spotlightX;
    mSpotY = spotlightY;
    if (mSpotX > 0 && mSpotY > 0) {
```

`          mDoSpot = true;
}
}

**The dotted lines are drawn in CropView onDraw() method as below,**

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

....
// Draw crop rect and markers
        CropDrawingUtils.drawCropRect(canvas, mScreenCropBounds);
        if (!mDoSpot) {
            CropDrawingUtils.drawRuleOfThird(canvas, mScreenCropBounds);
        }else {
            Paint wpPaint = new Paint();
            wpPaint.setColor(mWPMarkerColor);
            wpPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            wpPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            wpPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]
                    {mDashOnLength, mDashOnLength + mDashOffLength}, 0));
            p.setColor(mOverlayWPShadowColor);
            CropDrawingUtils.drawWallpaperSelectionFrame(canvas, mScreenCropBounds,
                    mSpotX, mSpotY, wpPaint, p);
        }
       
        CropDrawingUtils.drawIndicators(canvas, mCropIndicator, mIndicatorSize,
                mScreenCropBounds, mCropObj.isFixedAspect(), decode(mCropObj.getSelectState(), mRotation));
  }
```

Need to understand what is the need of dotted lines along with crop selection frame as below,
[crop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oG2y.png)`